# Losing the css properties - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a menu with vocals that redirect to the same page but showing different data thanks to the id passed through the anchor. I can print the ID in the blade but unfortunately I lose all the properties of the css. Why?

Menù in app.blade.php:

```
                            <li><a href="#">Articoli</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="/articoli/{{1}}">Persone</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/articoli/{{2}}">Business</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/articoli/{{3}}">Mindset</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

Route in web.php:

```
Route::get('/articoli/{articolo}', 'ArticoloController@show');
```

Controller:

```
    public function show($id){
    $articolo = Articolo::find($id);
    return view('articoli',['articolo'=>$articolo]);
}
```

Erros in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below instead of including it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your issue, but from V 5.2 I believe, Laravel binds models to routes automaticly. That is if the route's parameter name matches the model name in lowercase. In your case '{articoli}'

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

This could mean that your controller function is receiving a Eloquent Model instead of an ID. Typehinting like this avoids misunderstandings:

```
public function show(Articoli $articoli)
```

Also you won't have to find the model anymore. If you typehint a Model like so, and no model was bound to the route, a new Model will be inserted into the function. you can also try typehinting  (int $id), but honestly I don't know why you wouldn't use this awesome feature

Comment: i don't find files css and js because i have in the route the word "articoli"...example: http://project.dev/articoli/assets/
How can i remove the word articoli?

Comment: sorry. but I realy don't understand what loading css/js files has to do with anything you posted above =/. You will have to show more of your blade templates, on how you are handling your assets.

Comment: I found the error...i forgot to change the correct syntax to load css and js with {{}}.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's important to include files js and css with the correct syntax.
Like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

And not:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: The asset helper points to the public folder. It is not nessecary to use the asset helper if you write a correct src. Although I do advice you to study https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix and the use of npm.